# Keep prompting user for boolean input using while loop but it still repeats after parameter is met

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I'd like to keep asking for the user for `isMale` if they don't enter `True` or `False`.
However, the while loop keeps asking even when I enter `True` or `False`. I don't know why.

```
name = input("Name: ")
age = int(input("Age: "))
isMale = bool(input("Male? "))

while (isMale != True) or (isMale != False): #Is this correct?
    print("Wrong Input. Please type True/False")
    isMale = bool(input("Male? "))

if(isMale == True):
    print("His name is "+ name)
    print("He is {input} years old.".format(input= age))
    print("He is a Male")

elif(isMale == False):
    print("Her name is " + name)
    print("She is {input} years old.".format(input= age))
    print("She is a Female")
```

Comment: @quamrana I think I got that part correct. I tried changing it to that but it accepts even wrong inputs and automatically assume isMale is True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @frdspuzi bool('True'), and bool('False') are both going to be True because neither string is of length 0

Comment: I think the problem stems from ‘bool(input(...))’. It will *only* ever return True or False and never anything else. You probably need you own conversion and not python’ s notion of ‘Truthy’ and ‘Falsy’.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution but let me give some explanation when you cast an input to boolean will be like if an input is empty will be `false` and if an input contains something will be `true` no matter how the string is will always be `true` so that in that case I decided to create variable and initialize it to `false` and if one of the condition evaluates to `true` the variable called `notValid` will be `false`.

And I added some string method that will help you to format an input which are `strip()` to remove extra white spaces and `tittle()` which will capitalize an input.

and also all of the conditions are not checking between and input which is the form of string and boolean no I changed `isMale == True` to `isMale == 'True'` because both are string will be easy to compare them.

### Example

```
name = input("Name: ")
age = int(input("Age: "))
isMale = input("Male? ").strip().title()
notValid = True

if(isMale == 'True'):
    print("His name is "+ name)
    print("He is {input} years old.".format(input= age))
    print("He is a Male")
    notValid = False

elif(isMale == 'False'):
    print("Her name is " + name)
    print("She is {input} years old.".format(input= age))
    print("She is a Female")
    notValid = False

while notValid:
    if (isMale != 'True') or (isMale != 'False'):
        print("Wrong Input. Please type True/False")
        isMale = input("Male? ").strip().title()
    else:
        notValid = False
```